# Browser stalls when redirecting from Google Auth back to my application ... But only sometimes

Tags: google-cloud-platform

On Google's Cloud Platform I created an OAuth 2.0 Client ID under Api & Services / Credentials.

I defined it as a Web Application and added Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs. The two urls added are something like `https://localhost: ...`.

I copied the Client Id and Client Secret to my application ...

Because I am testing on OAuth consent screen I set the Publishing Status as testing and added to test users.

**PROBLEM**

When testing the application, using a test user, sometimes I am able to login.

At other times the browser stalls, after I enter my credentials, when getting back to my application. It is strange because this happens only sometimes ...

I get this problem with many than one browser like Chrome or Safari.

The browser seems to stall on the following URL:

```
https://accounts.google.pt/accounts/SetSID
```

After 60 seconds I get a timeout error on my application's callback url.

**UPDATE**

I'm starting the login process from the Angular Client application using [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js):

```
const settings: UserManagerSettings = {
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  authority: 'https://localhost:5000',
  client_id: 'spa',
  client_secret: 'secret',
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true,
  post_logout_redirect_uri: `https://localhost:5002/signout`,
  redirect_uri: `https://localhost:5002/signin`,
  response_mode: 'query',
  response_type: 'code',
  scope: 'openid profile email offline_access api',
  silent_redirect_uri: `https://localhost:5002/renew`
};

let manager = new UserManager(settings);

manager.signinRedirect();
```

This redirects to the Asp.Net Core with [OpenIdDict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) Auth application.

Then I opt to login with Google which calls the following method and redirects to Google:

```
public IActionResult Challenge(String provider, String returnUrl = null) {

  String redirectUrl = Url.Action("Callback", "User", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });

  AuthenticationProperties properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);

  return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);

}
```

The configuration of the Auth application is the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

  services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest)
    .AddJsonOptions()
    .AddFluentValidation();

  services.AddRouting(x => { x.AppendTrailingSlash = false; x.LowercaseUrls = true; });

  services.AddCors(x => {
    x.AddPolicy("Cors", y => 
      y.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5001", "https://localhost:5002").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
    });

  services.AddDbContext<Context>(x => {

    x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get<Options>().Database.Connection, y => {
      y.MigrationsHistoryTable("__Migrations");
      y.UseNetTopologySuite();  
    }).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(Environment.IsDevelopment())
      .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll);

    x.UseOpenIddict<Data.Entities.Application, Authorization, Scope, Token, Int32>();

  });

  services
    .AddIdentityCoreWithAuthentication<User>(x => x.AddDefaultOptions())
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddUserConfirmation<UserConfirmation<User>>();

  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(x => {
    x.AccessDeniedPath = "/denied";
    x.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    x.Cookie.Name = "auth";
    x.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40);
    x.LoginPath = "/login";
    x.LogoutPath = "/logout";
    x.SlidingExpiration = true;
  });

  services.AddOpenIddict()
  
    .AddCore(x => {

      x.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
       .UseDbContext<Context>()
       .ReplaceDefaultEntities<Data.Entities.Application, Authorization, Scope, Token, Int32>();
    
    })

    .AddServer(x => {

      x.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
       .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
       .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
       .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("/connect/introspect")
       .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo");

      x.RegisterClaims(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Email, OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Name, OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Role);

      x.RegisterScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess);
      
      x.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
       .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

  x.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate().AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

      x.UseAspNetCore()
       .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();

    })

    .AddValidation(x => {
      x.UseLocalServer();
      x.UseAspNetCore();
    });

    services
      .AddHsts(x => {
        x.Preload = true;
        x.IncludeSubDomains = true;
        x.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(1); 
    })
    .AddHttpsRedirection(x => {
       x.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
    });

  services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));

  services.Configure<Options>(Configuration);

  services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

} 

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application, IWebHostEnvironment environment) {

  application.UseHsts();
  application.UseHttpsRedirection();

  application.UseStaticFiles();

  application.UseRouting();
  application.UseCors("Cors");

  application.UseAuthentication();
  application.UseAuthorization();

  application.UseEndpoints(x => {
    x.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
  });

}
```

Comment: If you haven’t already tried, can you try authenticating with incognito mode? This would help us check whether this issue is with the browser cookies and auto filling. Can you also share the snippet on how your App initiates the authorization flow?

Comment: Yes, I tried with incognito mode and I get the same problem ... Consider the 3 steps: 1. Load Google Sign In page; 2. Enter Credentials; 3. Get redirected back to my application. Sometimes it fails on (1), other times fails on (3). One url where the browser usually stalls is `https://accounts.google.pt/accounts/SetSID` ... And sometimes everything works great. This makes it hard to determine what the problem is.

Comment: My client application is Angular 12 using [OIDC Client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js)`. And my authority application is ASP.NET Core 5 using [OpenIdDic](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core). I can add some code to my question is you think it would be useful.

Comment: Yes, please share how the application makes a request and handles the response. Can you also check the [HAR](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204410413-Generating-a-HAR-file-for-troubleshooting#h_2598b2df-ca9f-49bc-8166-054c9e5e665a) for possible delayed response and the response body during unsuccessful and successful requests and share your findings here.

Comment: @Ashish I added some information to my question. Does it help? I don't get any error ... It just stalls. The only error I get is after 60 seconds and my application gives a TimeOut exception.

Answer (score 0):

#### The best solution in this situation is to contact Workspace Support directly and provide the HAR file there.

To do this, I suggest you choose one of the options in this article [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) and for capturing the HAR file you can use Google's Admin Toolbox [tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/).